# Laravel subdomain route - NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, virtualhost

I'm working on API in my Laravel project, and have problem with setting up subdomain (Ubuntu).

I set up `Virtualhost`, `Routing`, enabled `vhost_alias`

VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.io
ServerAlias domain.io
DocumentRoot mypath

<Directory mypath>
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName api.domain.io
ServerAlias api.domain.io
DocumentRoot mypath

<Directory mypath>



            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

My route:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'api'.env('APP_HOST')], function() {

    Route::get('test', function() {
        return 'test';  
    });

});
```

Url `http://api.domain.io/` redirect to main domain `domain.io`. When I visit my route `http://api.happs.io/test` I get error (like there would not be that route):

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Comment: What does `env('APP_HOST')` resolve to? Wouldn't that have to be dynamic in order for you to switch between `domain` and `happs`? If you replace the `env()` with `happs.io` does the error still produce?

Comment: @camelCase It's working. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Was it the issue that `happs` wasn't included in `env('APP_HOST')`? I want to add as an answer for future visitors.

Comment: Yep, exactly that was the problem.

Comment: Great, I've added as an answer for future readers so they don't have to sort through comments. Glad you got it working, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `hosts` file is correct. The issue is your `env('APP_HOST')` is a static value but it needs to be dynamic with your setup.

An option, and likely the easiest approach (it's the one I use too), is to just create a route for the sub domain manually.

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'api.happs'], function() {
    // Do something
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid hardcoding 'api.happs' ? I would like to have the same routes/web.php for my production and test servers, without having to hardcode each domain

Answer (score 0):

Add `*.` before your domain name on `ServerAlias` and make sure you have a wildcard CNAME.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.io
    ServerAlias *.domain.io
    DocumentRoot mypath

    <Directory mypath>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Added `*.` before domain name. Wildcard is enable because of `vhost_alias`. Nothing changed, still not working.

Comment: @MichałLipa I meant do you have wildcard CNAME on your domain zone file? You can add it by entering `*` in column name of add CNAME recoed in your domain DNS manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, put the domain and subdomain in the NameServer:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.io api.domain.io
DocumentRoot mypath

<Directory mypath>
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Nothing changed, result is the same.

Comment: You removed the other virtualhost? I mean, you have two virtualhost. Put only one with the domain and subdomain, just how I do it